# Unable to ping 192.168.x.x series

Tags: router, dhcp, ping, route-server

My camera IP is in range of 192.168.x.x and I'm using IP in the range of 10.x.x.x  series DHCP. When I assign my PC a static IP 10.x.x.x and additional **ip 192.168.x.x**  I am able to ping my camera ip.

How do I ping my camera without adding my secondary IP?

Comment: What router and switch models do you have?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, devices with different IPs do not belong in the same network. 10.0.0.0/8 does not cover 192.168.0.0/16. The reason adding the second IP works is because the devices are on the same L2 network, but it's very mickey mouse.  So you have the following options;

1) Change the IP on your camera to something in the 10.x.x.x range that's within the subnet you're currently using. Easiest way to accomplish this is to do as Ron says and enable DHCP.

2) You add a second network to your nearest router/gateway, in the 192.168.0.0/16 to suit you camera, and make it shuffle packets between both networks.

My suggestion is that you try option 1, preferably DHCP first.

Answer (score 1):

your 10.x.x.x gateway should be able to reach the range of the camera ip, so that your pc could reach it . make sure that your GW could reach the range of the camera

Answer (score 0):

Enable DHCP on your camera....